# JQuery Slider -range not highlighted in colour

Tags: jquery

My range is not highlighted can anyone see any issue with the below code

```
   var minA = 0;
            var maxA = 900;

            if (getParameterByName("min")) {
                minA = getParameterByName("min");
            }
            if (getParameterByName("max")) {
                maxA = getParameterByName("max");
            }

            $("#sliderbar").slider({
                range: true,
                orientation: "horizontal",
                min: 0,
                max: 900,
                values: [minA, maxA],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#dnn$Menu1$lowerPrice").val(ui.values[0]);
                    $("#dnn$Menu1$upperPrice").val(ui.values[1]);
                    $("#low").val("$" + ui.values[0]);
                    $("#high").val("$" + ui.values[1]);
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#dnn$Menu1$lowerPrice").val(ui.values[0]);
                    $("#dnn$Menu1$upperPrice").val(ui.values[1]);
                    $("#low").val("$" + ui.values[0]);
                    $("#high").val("$" + ui.values[1]);
                    var url = "BuyAccessories?min=" + ui.values[0] + "&max=" + ui.values[1];
                    $(location).attr('href', url);
                    window.location.href(url);

                }
            });
            $("#low").val("$" + minA);
            $("#high").val("$" + maxA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was purely down to styles being set up incorrectly.
Adding the below made it visible.

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ffffff url(img/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222; }
.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 4px solid #aaaaaa; background: #cccccc url(img/ui-bg_flat_75_cccccc_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #222222; }
/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay { background: #aaaaaa url(img/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); }
.ui-widget-shadow { margin: -8px 0 0 -8px; padding: 8px; background: #aaaaaa url(img/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); -moz-border-radius: 8px; -khtml-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
```